# MySQL Database Error: Packets larger than max_allowed_packet are not allowed when insert

Tags: mysql, blob

I have installed mysql server 5.1. I am having a problem with BLOB fields in my MySQL database when i try to insert a huge file. Does anybody have any suggestion?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to fix this problem :

change the value of the [**`max_allowed_packet`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) variable in the configuration of your MySQL server.

How to know how much over what's allowed you are : not sure, but I would say that checking the size *(in bytes)* or your `insert` query should give you an idea.

For more informations, you should take a look at the following section of the MySQL manual : [**C.5.2.10. Packet too large**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html).

Comment: I add the following lines in the option file:                   [mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=1G but there is the same problem

Answer (score 0):

- Turn on Mysql Workbench and copy this line: “SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=16777216;” and Query the command.
- Turn off Mysql Workbench and restart.
- You can change your packet size to 32M by change the value of max_allowed_packet.